# Java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12518 when excecuting more than 60 select

Tags: java, oracle

i have a problem when creating a project in java, im connecting to my local DB on oracle, this is how i connect to the DB.

```
conexion = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"; 
this.usuario = "System";
this.password = "hereThePassword";
Class.forName( "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" );
conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(conexion,usuario,password);
```

and this is how i excecute a query on the DB.

```
ejecutarConsulta(String sql){
  Class.forName( "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" );
  conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(conexion,usuario,password);
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
}
```

i need to execute over 200 select in one loop (for) here's the code:

```
conexionBD BD = new conexionBD();
for(int i = 0; i < 500;i++){
        BD.ejecutarConsulta("select * from table");
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

The first 66 queries excecute right with no problem, what i can see is that when im on the select number 67 i get an exception with the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12518, TNS:listener could not hand off client connection
```

how can i excecute over 200 querys with the same Object BD?

Comment: Re-use your connection, don't open a new one for each request! (And the Class.forName trick only needs to be done _once_, at startup, before you create the first connection.)

Comment: It seems you are create a new connection for every single query, use the same connection for executing queries

Comment: That's right guys! i was creating a new connection when excecuting a new query, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error thanks to the comments belowthe question.

I was creating a new connection to excecute a single select, so i change the code like this:

Creating the connection:

```
Class.forName( "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" );
conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(conexion,usuario,password);
stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
```

and excecuting a single query:

```
ejecutarConsulta(String sql){
 System.out.println( sql );
 rs = this.stmt.executeQuery( sql );
}
```